# QtMultimedia flac support

Tags: qt, flac, qtmultimedia

im trying to use Qt library QtMultiMedia to play music. I want it to support .flac format as well.
I'm running Windows 8.1, i installed flac codecs from http://xiph.org/dshow/ . BTW it works perfectly with mp3s .

Sample code:

```
QMediaPlaylist plst;
plst.addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("path/file.flac"));
QMediaPlayer pl;
pl.setPlaylist(plst);
pl.play();
```

It does not play anything.

Comment: The path is incorrect, you can use '/' in paths or if you want '\' you will need to escape it so use: "path\\file.flac" And also check the current working dir so that you have the correct relative path (or test with an absolute path)

Comment: Just use `/` for separator, Qt has made it portable, it will translate to whatever it needs to be on the specific platform.

Comment: the path is not the problem, it was just a sample, even with correct path player just will not play .flac files

Comment: For me Qt media support in windows is horrid to say the least. It probably can't pick up the codec you are using.

Comment: same here. qt 5.4.1 debian jessie...

Answer (score 0):

I tried it without QMediaPlaylist and it worked...

```
QMediaContent content(QUrl::fromLocalFile("ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FILE"));
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer();
player->setMedia(content);

player->play();
```

I tested you code and it didn't work... even with absolute Path.

MAYBE OPTIONAL!!! ==>

I got a gstreamer error message which I inspected and ended up in learning gstreamer... even more error messages with 0.10 and 1.0. So I installed everything depending on gstreamer (both versions) and with the last update I was finally able to play sound in both versions

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-* gstreamer0.10-plugins-*
```

<== MAYBE OPTIONAL END

Your code still didn't work. So I compared...

I used pointers!

```
QMediaPlaylist* plst = new QMediaPlaylist();
plst->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FILE"));

QMediaPlayer *pl = new QMediaPlayer();
pl->setPlaylist(plst);

pl->play();
```

Now it works! (don't ask me why...).

**To sum it up: Pointers and Absolute Path [maybe gstreamer-plugins...]**

This is only a solution for Debian...

Can you tell me if it works in Windows?

How did you solve it?

If you close the application while still playing you get a SegFault.